# dtc command not found in yocto

Tags: yocto, device-tree

I am new to yocto and I am trying to build a basic image for nanopi-neo-air harware, there I am facing a error which i have shared here,please solve it.
Thank you in advance.

```
nano/poky/build/tmp/work/nanopi_neo_air-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_friendlyarm-r0/git/scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/basic

|   GEN     ./Makefile

| /nano/poky/build/tmp/work/nanopi_neo_air-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_friendlyarm-r0/git/scripts/dtc-version.sh: line 17:
dtc: command not found
| /nano/poky/build/tmp/work/nanopi_neo_air-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_friendlyarm-r0/git/scripts/dtc-version.sh: line 18: 
dtc: command not found

| rm -f .tmp_quiet_recordmcount

| *** Your dtc is too old, please upgrade to dtc 1.4 or newer
| /nano/poky/build/tmp/work/nanopi_neo_air-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_friendlyarm-r0/git/Makefile:1411: recipe for target 'checkdtc' failed

| make[1]: *** [checkdtc] Error 1
| make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| make[1]: Leaving directory 

'/nano/poky/build/tmp/work/nanopi_neo_air-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_friendlyarm-r0/build'

| Makefile:150: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
| make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
| make: Leaving directory '

/nano/poky/build/tmp/work/nanopi_neo_air-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_friendlyarm-r0/git'

| ERROR: oe_runmake failed

| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/harris/nano/poky/build/tmp/work/nanopi_neo_air-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_friendlyarm-r0/temp/log.do_compile.10821)
ERROR: Task (/home/harris/nano/poky/meta-nanopi-neo-air/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot_friendlyarm.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3253 tasks of which 3242 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/harris/nano/poky/meta-nanopi-neo-air/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot_friendlyarm.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Which version of poky are you using?

Comment: It is not any branch. "git branch -a" shows in master branch only.              
  * master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/bernard
  remotes/origin/blinky
  remotes/origin/clyde
  remotes/origin/daisy
  remotes/origin/danny
  remotes/origin/danny-next
  remotes/origin/denzil
  remotes/origin/dizzy
  remotes/origin/dora
  remotes/origin/dora-toaster
  remotes/origin/dylan
  remotes/origin/edison
  remotes/origin/elroy
  remotes/origin/fido
  remotes/origin/green
  remotes/origin/jethro
  remotes/origin/krogoth

Comment: What yocto branch you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear, you need dtc 1.4 at least, so check in poky/meta/recipes-kernel/dtc the current version.

Answer (score 2):

In yocto you might have missed the dependency to device tree compiler. Add this to the recipe to solve it.

```
DEPENDS_append = " dtc-native"
```

Comment: would that also work for compilation of dts files for `linux-rasbperrypi`?